# Drupal inline JavaScript

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

While adding an inline JavaScript code Drupal is adding `\` automatically.

```
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
     alert(\'hello world\');
  </script>
```

How can we avoid this? What is the correct way to add inline JavaScript code in Drupal?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to add the javascript code in your PHP code, it'd be better to use [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)().

Then inside the `$options` array, set `type` equals `inline`.

The following code adds inline javascript. (copied form documentation)

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
    array(
        'type' => 'inline', 
        'scope' => 'footer', 
        'weight' => 5
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your text format, if you want inline javascript to work, you need to have "Full HTML"